# Remove order in customer dashboard

Tags: magento2, orders, xml, dashboard

How to remove "recently order" in customer dashboard ?

I tried this :

```
<referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true"/>
```

but nothing happened

Comment: try that in `customer_account_index.xml` with same code. It is working with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_top" remove="true"/>
```

It will work for you. Let me know if further assistance needed.

Comment: Yes, that's it. The one I tried was for the sidebar on front office.

Comment: Please accept this, it will be helpful for others @MorganTartreau